# How to pass JLabel to another class

Tags: java, jlabel, getter

I am trying to pass a simple string from a purchase class by throwing it in a getter, then trying to retrieve it from another class called pconfirm. Then trying to set the text of a label in that form to the amount being passed.

#### Purchase.java

```
private JLabel lblamnt;

public String amount() {
    String gtext = lblamnt.getText();
    return gtext;
}
```

#### Pconfirm.java

```
private JLabel lblgamnt;

public Pconfirm() {
    Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    lblgamnt.setText("Test" + purchase.amount());
}
```

When i pass it it shows nothing.

I was under the presumption that you call it by Purchase.amount().

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is the reason behind “non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static), [Non-Static method cannot be referenced from a static context with methods and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862306/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-with-methods-and-va)

Comment: `Purchase` doesn't work here because you have a class, not a static method (as the error message is saying).  You need to make an instance of the class: `Purchase purchase = new Purchase(); purchase.amount();...`

Comment: *"I was under the presumption that you call it by Purchase.amount()"* - `new Purchase().amount()` would be more accurate, but, you would be wanting to use the instance of the object which was created to manage the original state

Comment: what is the name of your Purchase object? Use that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: i did instantiate it by ==> Purchase purchase = new Purchase(); and then next line is ==> lblgamnt.setText("Test" + purchase.amount());...But when i run it and try to pass the value nothing is there.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz your example from below is not what i need to bring over. I need the String from lblamnt in purchase.java to be sent to pconfirm.java. Thought your example worked its just not what i was looking for. Eg. IF lblamnt contains the string "1.345" i would need that string to be sent to pconfirm and to retrieve that string to be used.

Comment: Seriously? Not a single answer? @RAZ_Muh_Taz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an actual object to use the method amount()

In your Purchase class constructor hopefully you give access to the JLabel or the ability to set the text like so

**Purchase.java**

```
public void setTextOfJLabel(String text)
{
    lblamnt.setText(text);
}
```

Then you could do the following in

**Pconfirm.java**

```
private JLabel lblgamnt;
private Purchase purchObjName;

public Pconfirm() {
    purchObjName = new Purchase();
    purchObjName.setTextOfJLabel("The Purchase JLabel text");
    lblgamnt.setText("Pconfirm JLabel text and " + purchObjName.amount());
}
```

Unless you explicitly set the text before calling amount your text of the JLabel will be null. You could also do something where every Purchase JLabel text is the same until changed by the user using the method I provided and you can set a default text like this

**Purchase.java**

```
private final String defaultJLabelText = "Purchase Default Text"; 

public Purchase()
{
    lblamnt = new JLabel();
    lblamnt.setText(defaultJLabelText);
}
```

Comment: the method settextofjlabel is just setting the text. i need to retrieve the actual amount of that jlabel when i click the lblamnt contains a string and i need that string to be sent to pconfirm and that string needs to be stored ina  value. what yours does is just simply setting a fixed text. It doesnt pass the variable i need in the jlabel.

Comment: still stuck on this problem, driving me nuts.